# C++ : how to use templates to overload return type?

Tags: c++, templates, overloading

Say I have the following function:

```
template<typename T> 
shared_ptr<T> my_func(...){
    ....
    .... 
    return make_shared<T>(...);
}
```

And this function:

```
template<typename T> 
T my_func(...){
    ....
    ....
    return T(...);
}
```

Ideally, what I would like to do are things like:

```
vector<shared_ptr<T>> ptr_vec = { my_func<T>(...), my_func<T>(...), ... };

vector<T> non_ptr_vec = {my_func<T>(...),...};
```

Without having to "see" more than just the one function name, `my_func`.

---

Right now, I have the work-around where I am writing out:

```
template<typename T>
shared_ptr<T> my_func_shared_ptr(...){...}

template<typename T>
T my_func(...){...}
```

But this makes for more complexity.

How do I use the templates to accomplish this functionality?

Comment: You can't overload on return type alone.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude  ah ok, so this isn't possible? (nvm. seems like that would be a difficult question to answer in C++....  will delete if it is 'likely' to be impossible)

Comment: You can always use `struct`s as a workaround, but in your case, it's AFAIK impossible because how should the compiler decide if you want the `std::shared_ptr` or not when you call `my_func<T>(...)`? If you would pass a `std::shared_ptr` to `my_func`, then yes, it's possible.

Comment: @Rakete1111 got it.  thanks man.

Comment: If you use a `struct`, you can change the template parameter list to `template<typename T, bool makeShared = false>` then include at the end `if(makeShared) { ... } else { ... }`, but at that point, you probably should just make two functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, thanks to the input in comments, figured out another workaround.

if I introduce a "dummy" class to the template, it becomes sufficient to overload the return type.

```
template<typename T, typename U>
shared_ptr<T> my_func(...){...}

template<typename T>
T my_func(...){...}
```

Then,

```
struct ptr{};

A a = my_func<A>(...);

shared_ptr<A> a_ptr = my_func<A,ptr>(...);
```

And this becomes a label for the function...compiled and worked. I can also just use this in the inputs, rather than the template:

```
struct return_ptr{};
struct return_obj{};

template<typename T>
shared_ptr<T> my_func(...,return_ptr return_type){...};

template<typename T>
T my_func(...,return_obj return_type){...};
```

So that, when calling:

```
vector<shared_ptr<A>> a_ptrs = {my_func<A>(...,return_ptr()),...};

vector<A> a_objs = {my_func<A>(...,return_obj()),...};
```

Comment: Why is this better than just changing the name of the function?

Comment: @clcto I prefer this way for the purpose of reading code.  Now, I can toggle a single function.  In terms of personal memory (in my head), all I have to remember is one function, and the toggles (which are standard types: ptr, obj, etc.).  The IDE will prompt for the toggles, and if I write: `return_obj()` or `return_type()` as the last input, I have minimal memory overhead, and my code is more scannable/readable.  Secondly: no gain in time complexity. Empty struct construction is unit time, right?

Comment: @clcto  in other words: I think this is better than writing an underscored or camel cased sentence in my variable name.  (in my opinion)